# Infragistics WebDataGrid - Loading Edit Mode after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, events, infragistics

I have a strange problem, but it doesnt seem like I can find a solution:
I want to enter the edit mode of the WebDataGrid, when the user navigates from page X to the page with the grid.

My code is something like this:

function GridRowEnterEditMode(src, validationGroup) {

```
var savePageValidate = undefined;

if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) != "undefined") {
    savePageValidate = Page_ClientValidate;
    Page_ClientValidate = undefined;
}

var row = jQuery(src).parents("tr[type='row']").get(0)._object;
var editingCore = row.get_grid().get_behaviors().get_editingCore();

if (editingCore != null) {
    var rowEditingTemplate = editingCore.get_behaviors().get_rowEditingTemplate();
    if (rowEditingTemplate != null) {
        rowEditingTemplate.enterEditMode(row);
    }
}

if (savePageValidate != undefined) {
    Page_ClientValidate = savePageValidate;
}
if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) != "undefined" && validationGroup != null) {
    Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup);
}
```

}

While it works when I shoot this when a button is clicked, it seems like I cant find the correct event to load this after the page is loaded client side.

I tried document.ready, document.load, pageLoad, I setted a timer for a delay etc. etc., it always shoots at this code:
var row = jQuery(src).parents("tr[type='row']").get(0)._object;

Has anyone a idea, what I can do to delay this further or if there is a infragistics way to get this?

I asked in their forum as well, but didnt get a helpfull answer so far.

Matthias

Comment: My guess is that _row isn't yet defined when you are accessing it.  If you move the logic to the client side Initialize of the grid, then does it work?

Comment: Sadly the Client-Events initialize event of the grid gets ignored, I guess because I set the datasource in the server-side code. Tbh all other client side events get ignored as well and I didnt find anything about this in the Infragistics page.

Comment: I try it with setInterval and then

            $('#dgrRoles').focus();
            $('#dgrRoles').blur();
            var testObj = $('#' + obj.btnId).parents("tr[type='row']").get(0);

            if (testObj && testObj._object){

But funny enought, this works only when I move the mouse? How can that be possible?

Comment: I think im a step further, I reopen the case with more specific informations.

Comment: The client events will not be ignored because of where the data source is set.  Can you provide the markup/code where the event is set and the client function that you are setting it to?